# How to prevent v-main to shift when v-navigation-drawer is opened ? (Vuetify, Vue.js 2, Nuxt, Typescript)

Tags: layout, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I'm building an app with a `v-app` component at the root, using a `v-navigation-drawer` and I'd like to add a "Chat" page, where I'd also like to use `v-navigation-drawer`.

Problem is components don't display correctly. When I open the `v-navigation-drawer` of the app, it shifts the `v-main` of the chat page.

Opened app navigation

[image: Opened app navigation]

Closed app navigation, what I'd like regardless of whether the menu is collapsed or not
[image: Closed app navigation]

Here is my chat page's template:

```html
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      permanent
      color="deep-purple accent-6"
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
    >
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img
            src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQHYJ44y1nW7Rw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1634940206364?e=1645660800&v=beta&t=ni_NG94SNNVHDbzpVEtKwftayQzDy1bDtse2FavjDSU"
          ></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-title>Cosmic Darine</v-list-item-title>

        <v-btn icon @click.stop="mini = !mini">
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item v-for="item in menuItems" :key="item.title" link>
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-row> 
          I am a content
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <write-bar />
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue. Did you inspected the DOM with your devtools here?

Comment: Probably a matter of width or margins.

Comment: @kissu > I didn't add any CSS... I believe it's a property coming from Vuetify. I'll give update as soon as I find a solution. Thanks for your comment ! :)

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a Github link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. I added 'absolute' as a prop to v-navigation-drawer. The menu open above the content (I wanted that, so it's okay) and doesn't shift the content anymore. But if anyone would like to shift content when it opens only when needed, I guess you have to use the `@media` rule and `margin` with a negative value to shift back when the screen width is under a specific value.